# cstdint правильное использование

Tags: c++

Никак не могу определиться с правильным использованием `cstdint`.
Например, пишу тип `uint32_t` и я ориентируюсь на его размер при программировании логики, потом переношу на платформу где `int > 32` и мои `uint32_t` обрабатываются медленней. Хорошо, используем просто `int`, который всегда равен правильному значению. Если я перенесу на другую платформу, где `int < 32`, логика моей программы пострадает.

Может быть, тогда нужно программировать логику на самый маленький `int` и устанавливать значения `uint_leastN_t/unit_fastN_t`? Или жертвовать производительностью?

И `uint_leastN_t/unit_fastN_t` - чем они отличаются?

Comment: Бесплатный сыр только в мышеловке. Подумайте, что вы хотите. Хотите один и тот же размер на всех архитектурах? Ну так используйте его. Хотите на каждой архитектуре свой, оптимальный размер? Ну так пользуйтесь разными размерами на разных архитектурах и не жалуйтесь, что они разные, вы сами этого захотели.

Comment: Проблема может быть только если Вы используете собранные разными компиляторами бинарники вместе, тогда дело решит единый размер типов интерфейса.
Если взаимодействие между машинами - то дело решит сериализатор, который будет упаковывать пакеты так, чтобы всем было понятно.
В противном случае вообще нет проблем использовать int, как он есть, оптимальный для архитектуры.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да там различия в скорости минимальные, если вообще есть... Что ты вообще такое пишешь, что они во-первых оказались существенны, а во-вторых, что твоя программа будет запускаться на разных архитектурах? Сейчас на всех ПК размерность int'а 32 - независимо от битности. Вот с long'ом некоторые компиляторы решили сделать 64 на x64 (хотя, вроде линуксовые, на тот момент, когда я это читал). Это во-первых.

Далее, в большинстве случаев должно хватать всяких там size_t и подобных специфических типов, а также обычного int'а - вряд ли логика приложения завязана на размерности. Но если завязана, то логично соответствующий тип и использовать.

Answer (score 6):

Типы без упоминания `fast` или `least` используют **точные** размеры в битах. Причем на некоторых архитектурах этих типов вообще может не быть. О чем сказано в Стандарте 18.4.1:

```
namespace std {
    typedef signed integer type int8_t; // optional
    ...
}
```

Поэтому для большей переносимости кода приходится использовать либо `fast`, либо `least` версию. Для достижения максимального быстродействия или минимального расхода памяти соответственно. Такие типы уже обязательны к исполнению в Стандарте (отсутствует слово `optional`).