# Конфликт в определении типа данных

Tags: c++, ubuntu

Есть два h-файла, в которых определен тип данных:

- в первом случае (wintypes.h) как `typedef unsigned long DWORD;`
- во втором (stdafx.h) как `typedef uint32_t DWORD, LPDWORD;`

Первый тип данных (файл wintypes.h) нужен для функций в компилируемом файле xxx.cpp. В этот же xxx.cpp подключается Crypto.h, имеющий `#include "stdafx.h"`, **и** подключается winscard.h, имеющий `#include "wintypes.h"`.
При компиляции под Ubuntu возникает ошибка:

```
In file included from Crypto.h:27:0,
                 from xxx.cpp:12:
stdafx.h:29:26: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef uint32_t* LPDWORD’
 typedef uint32_t DWORD, *LPDWORD;  
                          ^
In file included from winscard.h:21:0,
                 from xxx.cpp:11:
wintypes.h:78:17: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef DWORD* LPDWORD’
  typedef DWORD *LPDWORD;
```

Не судите строго, я еще только учусь, могу многое не знать. Объясните, пожалуйста, как это можно исправить.

Comment: Эээ... Вы компилируете под Ubuntu исходники для Windows?

Comment: @Harry, этот проект писался для IOS. Его нужно скомпилировать под Linux. Я так понимаю win**.h скомпилится, но работать под linux не будет? Поясните, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `DWORD` соответствует `uint32_t`, то проблем быть не должно. Но раз уж они есть, получается, что это не так. Чтобы ругани компилятора на конфликтующие объявления не было нужно убрать этот конфликт. Например, добавить в одном из файлов директиву условной компиляции:

```
#ifdef WIN32
    typedef DWORD* LPDWORD;
#else
    typedef uint32_t* LPDWORD;
#endif
```

Реальные значения дефайнов и типов имеет смысл уточнять по ситуации. В вашей ситуации похоже, что файлы просто не адаптированы для сборки под различные платформы в составе единого модуля.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! Попробовал, но выходит так, что для одних файлов нужен typedef uint32_t DWORD, а для других typedef unsigned long DWORD.

Comment: @VadoM дело в том, что реальный размер типов вроде `unsigned long` не стандартизирован. И на разных системах может быть разным. А `uint32_t` это всегда 32-битный беззнаковый тип. Причём он даже не является обязательным к существованию в конкретно взятом компиляторе. В той ситуации, когда код собирается просто `unsigned long` совпадает с `uint32_t`, вот и все дела (хотя может быть и вовсе эта ветка не используется в коде, т.е. уже есть другие `#ifdef` исключающие переопределение). Можете ещё ознакомится с [ответом](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/476274/176217) в образовательных целях.

Comment: спасибо! попробую разобраться в этом