# Зачем использовать uint32_t?

Tags: c

Гарантируется ли, что типы с явным указанием размера (такие, как `uint32_t`, `uint64_t`, `uint16_t`) занимают одинаковое количество памяти на всех платформах (на десктопах, на мобилах, на микроконтроллерах)? Собственно, независимо от ответа, как эти типы можно использовать, есть ли какие-нибудь особенные задачи, где очень нужно знать размер в битах? Маски, флаги? Верно ли то, что в современном C обычный деревянный `int` под неким табу и не стоит использовать типы, размер которых меняется от платформы к платформе (здесь важны ссылки на стандарт, если он каким-то образом это регулирует или на мануалы к компилятору)?

Comment: Похожий [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/476192/176217).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [cstdint правильное использование](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476192/cstdint-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> типы с явным указанием размера

Стандарт гарантирует их размеры, но не их существование. Т. е. теоретически можно встретить платформу, на которой нет нужного типа. Зато если уж программа скомпилировалась, то размер типа ты точно знаешь.

Там ещё есть типы со словом `least`, например, `uint_least32_t`, если тебе надо хотя бы 32 бита.

> обычный деревянный int

Стандарт не гарантирует его размер.

> не стоит использовать типы, размер которых меняется от платформы к платформе

Всё зависит от задач. Если мне нужна 32-битная маска для перебора, то логично не полагаться на int. Если какой-то размер, то есть `size_t`, зависящий от битности программы. А если мне нужно вывести число процентов, то можно и обычный `int` взять.

Comment: Меньше крестов, но ответы от тех же людей :) P.S. уже нет.

Answer (score 4):

Типы вида `intN_t` или `uintN_t` обязаны иметь размер в битах, в точности совпадающий с `N`. Об этом написано в Стандарте языка (пример для `intN_t`):

> 7.20.1.1 Exact-width integer types
>   1 The typedef name `intN_t` designates a signed integer type with width `N`, no padding bits, and a two’s complement representation. Thus, `int8_t` denotes such a signed integer type with a width of exactly `8` bits.

Точный размер типов нужен при взаимодействии разных компонентов системы, которые могут работать на различных платформах. Т.к. `sizeof(int)` не регламентирован стандартом, его нельзя безопасно использовать в таких случаях. Но если переменная этого типа не выходит за границы одной системы, то разумнее опираться именно на базовые типы, вроде `int`.

Дополнительную информацию можно почерпнуть в похожем [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/476192/176217) по c++.

Answer (score 4):

Отвечаю на вопрос "зачем нужны типы фиксированного размера?"

---

Во-первых, для передачи структур данных по сети.

Висят 2 программы (с одинаковым исходным кодом, но каждая скомпилирована на месте) на двух разных системах и общаются сообщениями. Пусть, каждое сообщение состоит из 10 чисел по 4 байта. Но одна система 32 бита, а вторая - 64. Используете *int*? Флаг в руки. Всё сломается по очевидным причинам.

---

Во-вторых, для работы с различными форматами.

Картинки, архивы, видео, бинарные конфиги различных программ имеют фиксированные структуры. И если там какое-то поле является беззнаковым целым размером 4 байта, то *нужно* использовать платформонезависимые типы.

Примеров можно привести много :)

Comment: Для этого вопроса Вам надо переименоваться в `int3_t`:)

Comment: @alexout точно, а то новичков только запутываю :)

Comment: Эм.. передача по сети без специальной сериализации всё равно поломается, если встретятся big и little indian. С форматами файлов - так же. А ещё, по факту int сейчас везде int32, хотя этого никто и не обещал.

Comment: @Qwertiy специальная сериализация, конечно, поможет на этапе компиляции словить предупреждение. Но пример-то нужно было придумать. Возможно, с **int** пример не лучший, а вот какой-нибудь **size_t** очень даже годится

Comment: Ага, сейчас! **size_t** -- архитектурно зависимый тип. Его размер меняется.
@Qwerty Прелестная опечатка, бедные индейцы! (Ну и это, вы давно за микроконтроллеры садились? **int** в эквиваленте  разрядности **uint16_t** -- довольно распространённая штука.)

Comment: @0andriy я как раз имел в виду, что **size_t** годится для примера, где разные платформы, поэтому нужно использовать платформонезависимые типы.

Comment: @0andriy, если будешь писать ник с ошибкой, то сообщение прочитают случайно через два с половиной года ;)

Comment: @0andriy, так вроде суть того комментария и была про то, что если использовать архитектурнозависимый тип, то вероятность, что что-то развалится больше. Впрочем, сейчас long - отличный кандидат на x64 - он зависит от ОС - на винде 4, а в линуксе 8))

Answer (score 0):

Размер `int` может быть разным на разных платформах и может также зависеть от разных компиляторов. А при использовании того же `uint32_t`  точно известно сколько он занимает. Еще встречалась такая ситуация что `Int` не хватало. А использование  вещественных типов не допускается. Приходилось использовать `uint32_t`.