# Что влияет на количество памяти занимаемой разными типами данных

Tags: c++, x86-64, int

Как я понимаю, обычно тип `integer` весит 4 байта, в том числе и `unsigned integer`. 
Но есть случаи где в зависимости от разрядности процессора `integer` может иметь как 2 байта так и 8. 
Не понимаю, как разрядность влияет на размер целочисленного типа и что это меняет для разработчика кроме того, что в него можно вместить шире диапазон чисел(или меньший)?

**UPD**

Что значить переводить программу из `x32` в `x64`? Грубо говоря, это использования типов `x64`? Если я правильно понимаю, причина по которой программа написанная под `x64` не будет работать на `x32`, это оверхед по память в типах данных? 
Почему тогда мы можем допустим в `Visual Studio` выбрать под какую разрядность делать `build`? Как это будет влиять на размер самой программы и размер, который будут забирать обычные типы данных?

Comment: тип integer в каком языке программирования?

Comment: @Grundy например в С++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть такая [таблица](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) соответствия размеров фундаментальных типов в зависимости от используемой модели данных:

> [image: размеры типов]

Модель данных в общем случае не привязана непосредственно к железу (разрядности процессора), и зависит от используемой операционной системы (если она присутствует). При этом должно быть очевидно, что на 32bit процессоре не удастся запустить 64bit ОС, но обратное вполне себе имеет место быть.

Размер фундаментальных типов в конкретной реализации компилятора (т.е. под конкретную платформу) подбирается так, чтобы обеспечивать оптимальную производительность.

Помимо увеличения диапазона значений фундаментальных типов, бОльшая разрядность позволяет адресовать больше памяти. Например, при 32bit можно адресовать не более 4Gb, а при 64bit уже 16[Eb](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82).

Когда говорят о переводе программы с `x32` на `x64` имеют в виду, что должна обеспечиваться в первую очередь работоспособность программы в 64bit окружении. Т.е. что из-за изменения размеров типов ничего не сломается. Такого рода проблемы часто возникают, когда при первичной разработке закладываются на фиксированный размер фундаментальных типов, например, что указатель всегда будет 4 байта. А когда при сборке в 64bit режиме он "вдруг" становится в 2 раза больше программа просто начинает крашиться.

Поэтому, чтобы программа была переносима между `x32` ↔ `x64` при необходимости обеспечить нужную разрядность вычислений стоит [полагаться на типы из `<cstdint>`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/476192/176217).

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы это понять, лучше написать пару программ на ассемблере, например простейший калькулятор.

Основная причина разных размеров типа `int`, обычно кроется в количестве байт машинного слова архитектуры процессора (т.е. размер регистров), а также непосредственно в компиляторе.

Обычно представление следующее:

> **8 бит**
>
> `int` = 16 бит
>
> **16 бит**
>
> `int` = 16 бит
>
> **32 бит**
>
> `int` = 32 бита
>
> **64 бит**
>
> `int` = 32 бита

Необходимость 64 разрядных операционных систем и как следствие использования архитектур процессора возникла из-за роста памяти. Дело в том, что 32 разрядная ОС позволяет адресовать только 4 гигабайта оперативной памяти, т.к. `2^32 = 4294967296` байт.

Регистры процессора архитектуры x86

```
AL, BL, CL, DL - 8 бит
AX, BX, CX, DX - 16 бит
EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX - 32 бит
```

Comment: Лет 7 назад в универе, что-то там преподавали на ассамблере, но оно прошло как-то мимо меня. 
Регистр - это как временное хранилище данных и мы можем туда что-то записать используя какой-то ключ и потом по этому же ключу и достать? Получается 8ми байтовый `integer` используется только при явной на то нужде?

Comment: Там всё несколько сложнее, регистр это память непосредственно в процессоре, int может быть 8 байтовым, только при очень больших изощрениях с вашей стороны, там много проблем, например выравнивание

Comment: ещё есть упаковка